# Python Firebase TypeError: get() got multiple values for keyword argument 'connection'

Tags: python, firebase

Why does firebase keeps throwing me this error after following up with the tutorial.

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://project-1175938335914156477.firebaseio.com', authentication=None)
result = firebase.get('/charges', None,{'print': 'pretty'})
authentication = firebase.Authentication('MY KEY HERE', 'dahalbiplovechs@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
firebase.authentication = authentication
user = authentication.get_user()
print user.firebase_auth_token
```

That keeps throwing me

```
TypeError: get() got multiple values for keyword argument 'connection' under 'results' var.
```

Does this have to do with my API KEY? I'm using the key I got from

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/PROJECTNAME/settings/general/android:com.geeni
```

I got the key under "Web API KEY" What am I doing wrong?